# Are socket numbers realted to source port numbers

Tags: networking, sockets

I understand that socket=IP + port number but I was wondering if the internal number a socket has is related to the ephemeral port that is chosen for outgoing TCP connections?

For example this is from an lsof output of a volatility analysis of a memory dump from an Ubuntu 20.04 server:

*0xffff982e732e8000 httpd   1272       61 socket:[28657]*

*0xffff982e732e8000 httpd   1272       62 socket:[28658]*

Please ignore the fact that the process is called httpd.

Would 28657 and 28658 be used as source ports for those connections or are the numbers unrelated?

Comment: I do not see how this relates to Ubuntu but if you google understanding sockets you will find many articles you can read.

Comment: I have googled that and all I find are tons of articles telling me a socket is IP address + port. Yes, I know that. That's not what I'm looking for. And I stated that I'm using Ubuntu as other OSs might handle it differently.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu.

Comment: In a client-server-model connection, the server port is always a fixed number. The client may choose to use a fixed source port number, but this is unusual because the port number may already be in use. Therefore the client usually lets the OS decide which port number to use for the client process. That is usually a random port number (but guaranteed available).

Comment: Fun fact: long ago, the OS would simply take the next available incremental port number. That has been the cause of many security leaks, as it is highly predictable, and therefore can be spoofed by a malicious server.